# Getting the right values from IDs in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem in getting the actual values from ids. I can't understand the issue because while storing these values I am getting them using Ajax in a dropdown where it stores its ids from the dropdown. But when I am trying to get these values back, then it shows me those ids and not the actual values. I can't understand how I can get the actual values from these ids. I also plucked them in my index method in the controller, but that's not working because it's Ajax. Below is my code, please let me know if you want to know anything more about this.

Controller actions for creating the form.

```php
public function create()
{
    $classes = StudentsClass::pluck('class_name', 'id')->all();
    $rep_cat = ReportCtegories::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

    return view('admin.reports.create', compact('classes', 'rep_cat'));
}

public function getStudentId($id)
{
    $students = DB::table("students")->where("students_class_id", $id)->pluck("student_id", "id");

    return json_encode($students);
}

public function getStudentName($id)
{
    $students = DB::table("students")->select("id", DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name"))
        ->where("students_class_id", $id)->pluck("name", "id");

    return json_encode($students);
}
```

Ajax for getting values.

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //FOR LOADING STUDENTS
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('select[name="class_id"]').on('change', function () {
                var classID = $(this).val();
                if (classID) {

                    $.ajax({

                        url: '/reports/ajax/' + classID,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {

                            var markup = '';
                            markup = '<thead><tr class="filters"><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="options"></th><th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student ID<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student Name<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Report Category<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%;" class="align-middle text-center">Actions</th> <tr></thead><tbody>';

                            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                                markup += '<tr> <td><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="' + value.id + '"></td> <td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.student_id + '" name="student_id[]">' + value.student_id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.student_name + '" name="student_name[]">' + value.student_name + '<td><input type="hidden" value="' + value.report_categories_id + '" name="report_categories_id[]">' + value.report_categories_id + '</td>' +  '<td style=" width=12%" class="text-center"> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAttendanceModal' + value.id + '"""><button title="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></button></a> </td>' + '</td> <tr>';

                            });
                            markup += '</tbody>';
                            $('table[id="studentsData"]').html(markup);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend you use,

```
return response()->json($students)
```

Second pluck only return an array of ids(in your case)

I think you can try with this.

```
public function getStudentId($id)
{
    $students = DB::table("students")->where("students_class_id", $id)->get();
    return response()->json($students);
}
```

Comment: Sir I dont have any problem in storing data but I want to know that how I can get values from the ids in ajax. As normally pluck can give us the actual values from ids but here i am using ajax. How i can do that here ?